# Which HTTP methods does Subversion use?

Tags: svn

Our company's proxy server does not allow some HTTP methods which are used by Subversion's http protocol. As I will contact our IT support to enable them, I wonder what the full list of those methods is? Are there any other methods (besides the common ones) used by SVN other than PROPFIND?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Apache page on Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#http-methods):

```
 OPTIONS, PROPFIND, GET, REPORT,
 MKACTIVITY, PROPPATCH, PUT, CHECKOUT, MKCOL,
 MOVE, COPY, DELETE, LOCK, UNLOCK, MERGE
```

For read operations (read only access), the first 4 are enough:

```
OPTIONS, PROPFIND, GET, REPORT
```

See more [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/http-and-webdav/webdav-protocol)

Answer (score 3):

From the FAQ:

- Q: "What are all the HTTP methods Subversion uses?"
- A: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#http-methods